# In LR analysis report . How do i filter average response time only for passed transaction?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

In LR analysis report . How do i filter average response time only for passed transaction ? 
If i use the filer as "PASS" i dont see any change in the average response time.

[WithFilter "PASS"] Average Response time is 8.353
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1G4R.png

[With Out Filter] Average Response time is 8.353
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruUet.png

Please let me know how do i filter the response time only for the passed transactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Average Response time by default is only for passed transactions.  This is expected behavior for Analysis.

If you want the average response times to include failed, or only for failed transactions then you will be dancing through the results database file to the [Event Meter] and related tables for failed status items in a custom query